# Apache getting denied access to a directory on my local server

Tags: apache, permissions

I have OS X 10.5 with about 40 websites in the Sites directory.  I just downloaded one from my server to initialize a local copy but I am getting denied access.  The permissions seem fine but Apache is still giving me the 403.  Any ideas why this would happen?  Does it have to do with me downloading the files from the internet?

```
drwxr-xr-x  30 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   1020 Jul 17 19:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 55 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   1870 Jul 17 19:45 ../
-rw-r--r--@  1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    170 Jul  6 02:40 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    397 Jul  2 19:08 index.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal  15129 Jul  2 19:08 license.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   7638 Jul  2 19:08 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x  89 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   3026 Jul 17 16:24 wp-admin/
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal  40543 Jul  2 19:10 wp-app.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    220 Jul  2 19:10 wp-atom.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    274 Jul  2 19:10 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   3649 Jul  2 19:10 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    238 Jul  2 19:10 wp-commentsrss2.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   2550 Jul  2 19:10 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--@  1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   2458 Jul 17 16:41 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x   5 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    170 Jul 17 16:25 wp-content/
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   1254 Jul  2 19:11 wp-cron.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    220 Jul  2 19:11 wp-feed.php
drwxr-xr-x  77 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   2618 Jul 17 16:29 wp-includes/
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   1946 Jul  2 19:14 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   2341 Jul  2 19:14 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal  21019 Jul  2 19:14 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   7113 Jul  2 19:14 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    487 Jul  2 19:14 wp-pass.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    218 Jul  2 19:14 wp-rdf.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    316 Jul  2 19:14 wp-register.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    218 Jul  2 19:14 wp-rss.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal    220 Jul  2 19:14 wp-rss2.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal  21213 Jul  2 19:14 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--   1 TAmoyal  TAmoyal   3434 Jul  2 19:14 wp-trackbac
```

Thanks

Comment: This question might be better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: Just for covering bases what's in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to double-check the permissions. All folders should have a+x and all files should have a+r. If that is the case, check to see if there are any symbolic links in there. Depending on your Apache configuration, symbolic links might not be allowed. You can use the "SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" (more secure) or "FollowSymLinks" (less secure) options in your Apache configuration to enable symbolic links.

Comment: You might also want to check out the following link in case it applies:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1564667

Comment: symlinks shouldn't be the issue.  i have 10 local wordpress sites and just added another.  all work fine except for this one

Comment: i was wrong, symlinks were disabled and that was the issue.  thanks for the insight